# Does deploying a databse project affect other databases on a database servers?

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, database-project

I have a database for which I created a database project using visual studios.
I have created an Azure Repo and built it using Azure Build Pipelines.
I want to create a release pipeline for the same and deployment group to connect to the server.
My concern is I have multiple databases on the database server and I don't want them to get affected due to the deployment.
As far as I know the changes should affect only the concern database and not other databases.
Am I right or the TSQL scripts created will affect other databases too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deploy a single database it only your sql script/dacpac affect only this one database. However, if they are on the same server, your deployment may have some impact on other databases as resource utlization may increase during deployment.

Comment: I'm aware about the resources utilization factor. I just wanted to know that data and  structure of other databases won't be affected.

Comment: You know, when you deploy changes to database, you need connection string. And connection string point you to database, not to server.